# Not able to start Ubuntu 20.04 after fresh install

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, kernel

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 by erasing earlier windows 10. Installation was successful but after restarting its giving me this error -
kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown- block (0,0).

Laptop specifications:
Ram-8gb, sdd-512gb.
Used bootable usb stick as a installation media.

[image]

Comment: use the rescue shell at grub boot screen prompt

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this, can you please elaborate more on this.

Comment: Does your computer have a CD drive?